# Redis cache showing Status not connected

Tags: caching, redis-cache

I installed redis object cache on my server and then uSed this plugin to flush the caches... This worked for me for 5 to 6 days.. after that. Status not connected os showing....
I'm also using fastcgi cache. But, both was working since 5 days...Today I got this error with redid cache.
The error is:

Status: Not Connected

Client: PhpRedis (v3.1.6)

Drop-in: Valid

Connection Exception: Redis server went away

(RedisException)

Redis Extension: 3.1.6

Predis Client: 1.1.1

PHP Version: 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Multisite: No

Global Prefix: "wp_"

Blog Prefix: "wp_"

WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT: "domain.com"

Global Groups: ["blog-details","blog-id-cache","blog-lookup","global-posts","networks","rss","sites","site-details","site-lookup","site-options","site-transient","users","useremail","userlogins","usermeta","user_meta","userslugs"]
Ignored Groups: ["counts","plugins","blog-details","blog-id-cache","blog-lookup","global-posts","networks","rss","sites","site-details","site-lookup","site-options","site-transient","users","useremail","userlogins","usermeta","user_meta","userslugs","themes"]
Dropins:

advanced-cache.php v by
Redis Object Cache Drop-In v1.4.1 by Till Krüss
Plugins:
Ads.txt Manager v1.1 by 10up (Active)
Advanced Ads v1.11.2 by Thomas Maier (Active)
Autoptimize v2.4.4 by Frank Goossens (futtta) (Active)
EWWW Image Optimizer v4.6.3 by Exactly WWW (Active)
Idblog Core v1.1.5 by Gian Mokhammad R (Active)
Lazy Load by WP Rocket v2.0.3.2 by WP Rocket (Active)
Nginx Cache v1.0.4 by Till Krüss (Active)
Redis Object Cache v1.4.1 by Till Krüss (Active)
Related Posts v5.12.88 by iLen (Active)
WP-Optimize v2.2.12 by David Anderson, Ruhani Rabin, Team Updraft (Active)
Yoast SEO v9.6 by Team Yoast (Active)

Answer (score 1):

i found answer.. some of the software was outdated on my nginx server for this i run some of the command.

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

after this you need to edit redis configuration file. in my case file was at `sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`

here you have to confirm that you have replaced `#maxmemory` with

```
maxmemory 128mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu
```

then restart the redis and php using

```
sudo service redis-server restart
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

then go for test using the code given below:

```
redis-cli
ping
set test "It's working"
get test
```

this will show the result `"it's working"`

now use command `exit` to exit

congratulations, problem solved